# Consuming SOAP Services ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, soapheader

I am working on an ASP.NET 3.5 C# Web Application in which I have to consume 3rd party web services. Their documentation says the following information needs to be passed in the SOAP header:

- **wsse: SecurityTokenReference**: Value is the public key of the X.509 certificate
- **wsse:UsernameToken**: Username and Password
- **ds:Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"**

  I have a X.509 certificate as well as the Username and Password. I have added a Service Reference to my project and now I am trying to figure out a way to pass this information in the SOAP header.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the webservice build using .net ?

Comment: I am not sure about the technology used for building the web services. All I have is a URL to the WSDL.